# access iframe with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the following code, the alert works fine and prints "DIV : IFRAME" as it should however it then says that cNs[1].childNodes[1].document has no properties.

Html:

```
<div id="WinContainer">
 <div style="display: none;"><iframe id="frame1" name="frame1"></iframe></div>
 <div style="display: none;"><iframe id="frame2" name="frame2"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var cNs = document.getElementById('WinContainer').childNodes;
alert(cNs[1].tagName + ' : ' + cNs[1].childNodes[1].tagName);
cNs[1].childNodes[1].document.location = 'someurl.pl';
```

BUT if I do this:

```
frame1.document.location = 'someurl.pl';
```

it works fine.

Comment: Your code actually doesn't alert "DIV : IFRAME". See http://jsbin.com/owofo/edit cNs[1].childNodes[1] is null.

Comment: IE and firefox are indexing them differently

Comment: @unknown: not with the markup in the question. `cNs[1].childNodes[1]` is borked in all browsers, since you don't have whitespace anywhere between tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `iframe` DOM node has a property called `contentDocument` which will be the equivalent of `document`, but for that `iframe`.

If the page being displayed is on another server tho (or even on a different port on the same server) you will get a security exception trying to access it.

Not sure if this works for IE.

Comment: frame1.document.location works because you are changing the frame's location without being able to read anything from it. For example, you could have a large iframe which loaded either Facebook or Myspace when you clicked a button, but the javascript may not have access to the contents of either, because it could steal your personal data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reference the reliable **contentWindow** property to get to that iFrame's document object as such:

```
cNs[0].childNodes[0].contentWindow.document
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with javascript but it looks like you're using cNs incorrectly. It looks as though it is an array containing the child nodes and the code

```
cNs[1].childNodes[1].document.location = 'someurl.pl';
```

is trying to get the child nodes that do not exist. Try this it might work.

```
cNs[1].document.location = 'someurl.pl';
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: frame1 should be:

`cNs[0].childNodes[0].document.location`

Remember that things are 0 indexed.

Comment: in IE this works, in firefox my elements are indexed at 1,1 not 0,0

Comment: Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html for a quick tutorial on browser detection if things are being indexed differently.